# Prisma ORM & PostgreSQL applying pagination on related table results

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, prisma

I am using Prisma ORM with typescript and trying to apply pagination on the related table data. I couldn't find any detailed information in the official documentation of the Prisma about the topic (
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries and
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/pagination
). I'm trying to get the results of below SQL query but Prisma doesn't allow to pass any take or skip params on the indexes data. Thanks for help.

**Update:** I have added an another query at the end of the post and it is working correctly. Probably the first query that I've posted was wrong but I want to hear the explanation from someone who can explain the issue better.

```
SELECT title FROM indexes as idxs 
INNER JOIN index_users idxu ON (idxu.index_id = idxs.id) WHERE 
idxu.user_id = 986
LIMIT 2;
```

Which corresponds to (intuitively)

```
const result = await this.client.indexUsers.findMany(
            {
                where: {
                    userId: 986,
                },
                select: {
                    indexes: {
                        take: 2, // <-- Doesn't allow this
                        select: {
                            title: true,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        );
```

**Prisma schema of the related tables**

```
model indexes {
  id                Int                    @id(map: "pk_indexes") @default(autoincrement())
  title             String?                @db.VarChar(255)
  slug              String?                @db.VarChar(255)
  publicRights      enum_index_visibility? @default(off) @map("public_rights")
  privateLinkRights enum_index_visibility? @default(off) @map("private_link_rights")
  privateLinkCode   String?                @map("private_link_code") @db.VarChar(50)
  clonedFrom        Int?                   @map("cloned_from")
  createdAt         DateTime               @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt         DateTime               @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  index_users       IndexUsers[]
  invitations       invitations[]
  links             links[]
}

model IndexUsers {
  id         Int                    @id(map: "pk_index_users") @default(autoincrement())
  indexId    Int                    @map("index_id")
  userId     Int                    @map("user_id")
  permission enum_index_users_role? @default(view)
  createdAt  DateTime               @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt  DateTime               @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  indexes    indexes                @relation(fields: [indexId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_index_users_indexes")
  users      users                  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_index_users_users")

  @@map("index_users")
}

model users {
  id              Int          @id(map: "pk_users") @default(autoincrement())
  name            String?      @db.VarChar(100)
  username        String?      @db.VarChar(100)
  email           String?      @db.VarChar(100)
  password        String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  picture         String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  location        String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  visibility      Boolean      @default(true)
  bio             String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  urlWeb          String?      @map("url_web") @db.VarChar(255)
  urlFacebook     String?      @map("url_facebook") @db.VarChar(255)
  urlTwitter      String?      @map("url_twitter") @db.VarChar(255)
  urlInstagram    String?      @map("url_instagram") @db.VarChar(255)
  urlPatreon      String?      @map("url_patreon") @db.VarChar(255)
  verified        Boolean      @default(false)
  externalLogin   Boolean?     @map("external_login")
  apiKey          String?      @map("api_key") @db.VarChar(255)
  zapierToken     String?      @map("zapier_token") @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt       DateTime     @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime     @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)
  verificationKey String?      @map("verification_key") @db.VarChar(255)
  index_users     IndexUsers[]
  user_token      UserToken[]
}
```

[image]

**Updated query which works correctly**

```
    const result = await this.client.indexes.findMany(
            {
                take: 2,
                select: {
                    title: true,
                },
                where: {
                    index_users: {
                        some: {
                            userId: 986,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        );
```